# Appium (Android): Time out on start-up after running 1 test on device

Tags: android, adb, appium

TL;DR: I can run only 1 test against a certain device, then every other attempt to connect my app to an ADB session, manually or via an Appium server call, fails. How do I resolve this so that I can resume automated testing?

The Appium desired_capabilities for my device includes `noReset = True`. All other desired_capabilities except device identifiers are shared among and work for all my other devices.
This error was not observed until I added `driver.reset()` to one of my tests. Removing that line of code has not resolved this issue. Because of this, I suspect that Appium is not the root cause of this error, but rather highlighted it. My desired capabilities are:

```
`
'platformName': 'Android',
'platformVersion': '8.0',
'deviceName': 'WVGA_API_26',
'avd': 'WVGA_API_26',
'app_package': 'com.ferly.ferly',
'app_activity': 'host.exp.exponent.experience.ShellAppActivity',
'app_wait_package': 'com.ferly.ferly',
'automationName': 'UiAutomator2',
'noReset': 'true',`
```

Attempting to initialize any driver session that uses the affected device gives the following error in Appium:

> WebDriverException: Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot start the 'com.ferly.ferly' application. Visit https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md for troubleshooting. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command 'C:\Users\Jeff\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5558 shell am start -W -n com.ferly.ferly/host.exp.exponent.experience.ShellAppActivity -S' timed out after 20000ms'. Try to increase the 20000ms adb execution timeout represented by 'adbExecTimeout' capability

Running the command in my Windows shell: `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5556 shell am start -W -n com.ferly.ferly/host.exp.exponent.experience.ShellAppActivity -S`, where emulator-5556 is the affected device, gives the following output:

> Stopping: com.ferly.ferly
>    Starting: Intent { cmp=com.ferly.ferly/host.exp.exponent.experience.ShellAppActivity }
>   ^C (manual break after 2 minutes of waiting.)

On my emulator, the app opens and can be used as I expect, but the adb session does not recognize that the app is opened.

Running the same command, but for an unaffected device, say emulator-5558, succeeds with this output:

> Stopping: com.ferly.ferly
>   Starting: Intent { cmp=com.ferly.ferly/host.exp.exponent.experience.ShellAppActivity }
>   Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front
>   Status: ok
>   ThisTime: 0
>   TotalTime: 0
>   WaitTime: 872
>   Complete

Workarounds: Uninstalling the Appium Settings app on the affected device after every test allows one test to be run on that device.

What is the core issue I'm facing and how do I solve it? If it matters, my test scripts are all written in Python.

Answer (score 2):

I have increased the time out to 600 seconds as below.

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(600, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

The issue seems to have fixed for me.